# HTTP GET request with a TCP socket doesn't return anything

Tags: .net, http, tcp, get

I have this code in .NET:

```
        Socket Connector = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        string IP = "198.41.208.139";
        Connector.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 80));
        Connector.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET / HTTP/1.1"));
        byte[] Data = new byte[1024];
        Connector.Receive(Data);
```

The IP belongs to http://reddit.com/, but the GET request doesn't return anything. The Receive method is blocking the program indefinitely. The same thing happened when I tried with the websites http://imgur.com/ and http://youtube.com/

Why does this happen, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to append `"\r\n\r\n"` to the request as per [RFC2616 HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5).

Also for HTTP 1.0+ you should add a `Host:` header (mandory for 1.1, recommended for 1.0):

```
Connector.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: reddit.com\r\n\r\n"));
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much! Your answer can be accepted in 8 minutes from now, so I'll accept it then.

Comment: You're welcome! And if someone else gives you a better answer you shouldn't hesitate to accept it :-)

Comment: Actually, with HTTP/1.1 you also need to add a Host header to the request. At least the standard says so, while not all servers will actually require it.